# how to get the enum values one by one using a loop

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

i'm trying to get the enum values one by one using a for loop without the need to specify all possible values like i'm doing in the code  `Value.As` be replaced by something like `Value.values()`but when i try this it doesn't work for me :

```
public class Deck {

    private LinkedList<Card> cardList;

    public Deck(int nbBox) {
        this.cardList = new LinkedList<Card>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nbBox; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++) {
                cardList.add(new Card(Value.AS, Color.CLUB));
            }

        }


    }

    public Card draw() {
        return null; // not done yet 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Here is the deck : " +cardList;
    }

    public LinkedList<Card> getCardList() {
        return cardList;
    }

    public void setCardList(LinkedList<Card> cardList) {
        this.cardList = cardList;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`for-each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) on the `values()`. This reads as for each suit, for each value add a new card with the suit and value to the `List`. Also, you could use diamond operator `<>` like,

```
public Deck(int nbBox) {
    this.cardList = new LinkedList<>(); // <-- diamond operator

    for (int i = 0; i < nbBox; i++) {
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
            for (Value value : Value.values()) {
                cardList.add(new Card(suit, value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
enum Mobile {
    Samsung(400), Nokia(250),Motorola(325);

    int price;
    Mobile(int p) {
       price = p;
    }
    int showPrice() {
       return price;
    } 
}

public class EnumDemo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("CellPhone List:");
        for(Mobile m : Mobile.values()) {
            System.out.println(m + " costs " + m.showPrice() + " dollars");
        }

        Mobile ret = Mobile.Samsung;
        System.out.println("The ordinal is = " + ret.ordinal());
        System.out.println("MobileName = " + ret.name());                      
   }
}
```

The output will be:

```
CellPhone List:
Samsung costs 400 dollars
Nokia costs 250 dollars
Motorola costs 325 dollars
The ordinal is = 0
MobileName = Samsung
```